# nginx django uwsgi 502 bad gateway

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy my django web application on ubuntu 14.04 server 64 bit with nginx and uwsgi. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial but i am getting a 502 bad gateway error.

Steps i followed:

1. Installed dependency and and virtual environment.
2. Tried the django webapp using uwsgi command:

`uwsgi --http :8001 --home /home/pnb/pnb --chdir /home/pnb/pnb/pnb -w pnb.wsgi`

3. Create a pnb.ini file in the directory `/etc/uwsgi/sites`:

[uwsgi]

```
project = pnb    # Virtual environment name in home directory
base = /home/pnb    # Home directory path
chdir = /home/pnb/pnb     # Virtual Env Directory
home = /home/pnb/pnb/pnb       #Django Project Directory with manage.py
module = pnb.wsgi:application     # project name

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /home/pnb/pnb/pnb/pnb.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

4. Created an upstart script `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`

description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid pnb
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

5. created and nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites/available/pnb`:

   upstream django {
       server unix:/home/pnb/pnb/pnb/pnb.sock;
   }

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name pnb.com; # IP Address or FQDN

   ```
   location /static/ {
       root /home/pnb/pnb/pnb;
   }

   location / {
       include         uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/pnb/pnb/pnb/pnb.sock;
   }
   ```

   }

Using this configuration I am getting an `502 bad gateway` error when I go to pnb.com.

There is the nginx error log:

```
2016/06/12 06:30:10 [crit] 12517#0: *4 connect() to unix:/home/pnb/pnb/pnb/pnb.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.218.89.140, server: pnb.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/pnb/pnb/pnb/pnb.sock:", host: "pnb.com"
```

How to correct this error?

EDIT:

Now that i have checked the pnb.sock file is not creating in the directory. Does it have to do something with file permissions?

Same configuration was working for my another project.

Comment: On ubuntu, the convention is to create sockets in the directory `/var/run/`. You could put it anywhere, but you have to pay attention that the permissions are correct. Both processes that connect to the socket must have read and write access to the socket file and `rx` permission to the directory (and all parents). I assume that *uWSGI* would create the socket when it starts up the application.

Comment: @HåkenLid this is my second deployment using the above tutorial. First time it worked without any error. This time only it is throwing me this error. I tried changing the permissions to 666 in pnb.conf but still not working

Comment: And you get no error messages when you start uWSGI? `sudo service uwsgi start`

Comment: @HåkenLid No. Uwsgi and nginx dont throw any error while starting. I also tried changing the directory of socket to /var/run. Still not working